# SQL Summarising Data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm pulling some data out of a MSSSQL database using C# that keeps track of employees and their hours worked.  I'm simply using a regular simple select statement to pull out the relevant data. I'd like to be able to summarise the data (not sure if I'm using the correct word).

For example, the text in black in the following image is what I have at the moment, but I'd like to be able to add in the text in red somehow. What would be the best approach to doing this? Splitting up into smaller queries perhaps?

[image]

Comment: do you want this as a separate row or in another column?

Comment: What is the final tool, that will display the data ? usually the GUI components, such as grid, pivot grid, excel or any reporting tool, have such capabilities integrated inside of them. Look for "running totals". That will be Your answer

Comment: if you're gonna use this in crystal reports, and need to show all lines, and a final total (as I see here), I think it's better to calculate the totals in the report directly

Comment: @Marty - This isn't "Running Totals", its just summarized data. "Running Totals" is something far more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008+ you can use `GROUPIN SETS`. In your example, try this:

```
SELECT  SalesPersonCode, 
        SalesPersonName, 
        [Date], 
        SUM(HoursWorked) HoursWorked
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS( (SalesPersonCode, SalesPersonName, [Date]),
                        (SalesPersonCode),())
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the total hours worked by sales person:

```
SELECT SalesPersonCode, SUM(HoursWorked) AS [HoursWorked]
FROM table
GROUP BY SalesPersonCode
```

Should return:

```
001  26
002  24
```

To get the total hours worked:

```
SELECT SUM(HoursWorked) AS [HoursWorked]
FROM table
```

Should return:

```
50
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will get you all of the data except the grand total in one query:

```
select t1.salespersoncode,
    t1.salespersonname,
    t1.date,
    t1.hoursworked,
    x.TotalHours
from yourTable t1
inner join
(
    select salespersoncode,
        sum(hoursworked) TotalHours
    from yourTable
    group by salespersoncode
) x
    on t1.salespersoncode = x.salespersoncode
```

If you then want the grand total for all hours:

```
select sum(hoursworked) GrandTotal
from yourTable
```